# Eventlet throwing unintelligble exceptions

Tags: python, asynchronous, eventlet

I'm using Eventlet's example code found here: http://eventlet.net/doc/examples.html#producer-consumer-recursive-web-crawler

Halfway through the run, I encounter multiple instances of the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/eventlet-0.9.9-py2.6.egg/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 285, in fire_timers
    timer()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/eventlet-0.9.9-py2.6.egg/eventlet/hubs/timer.py", line 56, in __call__
    cb(*args, **kw)
TypeError: exceptions must be classes, or instances, not bool
```

Comment: I can't install eventlet without installing setuptools (which I refuse to do) so I can't reproduce or try to debug this; code inspection reveals no obvious place, there are just a few bare `raise` statements that might re-raise "anything".  To debug this you'll have to "instrument" the code by adding logging calls (good luck doing that in an `egg` -- part of why I just won't install `setuptools`!) and a lot of pondering. Or, just open a bug on eventlet's issue tracker, wherever it may be. "Unintelligible" is incorrect -- clearly some spot is raising a `bool` -- but, hard to find in an egg!-)

Comment: Curious, why won't you install setuptools? Do you consider it a security risk or something?

Comment: I don't understand Alex's comment about adding debug code to an egg being hard: so long as the egg was installed unzipped (and it looks from Rhubarb's traceback that it was) it's no harder than editing any other source file in Python's standard library.
Of course to be safe when doing such things you should use virtualenv and then you can install and hack eggs without affecting any of the standard code.

I'm on Windows at the moment, so I can't get eventlet to install for a useful answer.